# OpenGL - glBlendFunc

Tags: opengl, glblendfunc

I've been trying to find some concrete maths behind the innerworkings of glBlendFunc.

Just to clarify, I know that the blending equation is:

srcChannels * srcFactor + dstChannels * dstFactor = channelsRendered.

my question is, are srcChannels, dstChannels and channelsRendered the 3-vector (r,g,b) or the 4-vector (r,g,b,a)?

since (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0) and (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2) should look the same, there may be room for ambiguity here.

Answer (score 1):

`glBlendFunc` works on all four channels; `glBlendFuncSeparate` separates RGB from alpha.

The [glBlendFunc reference page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) describes all the different blend modes and the operations applied to the different channels. [glBlendFuncSeparate](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFuncSeparate.xhtml) does the same including operations on the alpha channel.

Comment: Also, what does openGL interpret a completely transparent pixel as from a png file? (0,0,0,0) or (1,1,1,0)?

Comment: I found out that openGL interprets a completely transparent pixel as (1,1,1,0), why is this? is there a way to make it interpret them as (0,0,0,0)?

Comment: @MattPeck: "*what does openGL interpret a completely transparent pixel as from a png file?*" Neither; OpenGL does not *interpret* a PNG file. You *give* OpenGL arbitrary pixel data; OpenGL doesn't know or care that it came from a PNG file. It's the PNG decompressor that decides what a "transparent" pixel looks like, not OpenGL.

Comment: @MattPeck Your question doesn't exactly make sense.  A transparent pixel is transparent by virtue of having a zero alpha component.  So, if that pixel is the source color, and you're using `GL_SRC_ALPHA` the fragment's color is irrelevant.  However, I don't think that's what you're really getting at.  If the problem is that a PNG file uses white when you want black, you could either remap this in a shader, or use `glPixelMap` if you're going prehistoric (and if you are, please use a shader).  The reason this works is that fragment shaders are executed before the fragments are blended.